# If I don't participate in research in first couple of years of PhD , how much am I losing?

Tags: phd, research-process, masters, advisor

I completed my MS in Human Computer Interaction (HCI) and was planning to do an PhD in Operations Research. But after first few weeks in program , I decided it was not what I wanted to do in long term and dropped out.

There is a background to this- my untenured MS advisor refused to sponsor my PhD . Another well known professor in the department came forward and offered me a good stipend but I dropped out from his lab after couple of weeks.

Things had become too caustic even before I joined his lab. The PhD professor wanted me to help him with some algorithms in the final month of my MS, but my MS advisor shooed him multiple times saying that I was very busy, when in fact I was free all the time. My MS advisor wanted me to make her a co advisor and get her a piece of the tenured professor's project, it didn't work out and since then she has become pretty vengeful towards me. She rejected job offers from our research sponsors after MS saying I was doing PhD and was not interested in working for them.

I think at this point I have lot of ill will against me in my department mainly due to active efforts to undermine me by my MS advisor.

In my university ,we need to take around 30-40 credit hours of subjects and pass candidacy and continue the dissertation.

I am taking an completely different route to PhD. I am taking 9 credit hours every semester (full time course load is 6 credit hours) and at same time working full time as Data warehouse SW developer.

It's very strenuous(My long commute, job and courses and assignments occupy at least 17-18 hours of my day) but I am able to manage them and it's working pretty well as I get paid around 135K at my job.

*Is this is an ideal approach until I finish my subjects and then see if any HCI lab in my department can take me in? Can I expect things to calm down in 2 years time.or what can i do right now to improve on this situation?*

Or am I really hurting myself here. My concern at this point is after my candidacy, no lab will take me back because of no recent research work. By the way, I don't need to finalize an advisor for the dissertation right now, I can take candidacy exam in dept. by forming a temporary committee .

One advantage I may have is I will have enough money by that time to volunteer in a lab for around an year to prove my worth. But again I am afraid my MS advisor may actively sabotage any of those efforts. I have been afraid and tensed for past few days thinking about this.

Edit : I am from Midwest US

Comment: What is HCl? How long is a PhD in your country? Who funds you? Also, why would you MS advisor actively try to hurt you? If you have some proof, you should consider bringing this up to the department.

Comment: I don't understand either how your PhD prof. offered you work, but she managed to reject it. Did he offer it to you through her? How did you learned that he made an offer? Why didn't you tell him you were indeed free?

Comment: I presume he means that someone told the MS supervisor about a job that James might be interested in, but the supervisor ran them off without consulting James.

Comment: @Davidmh , HCI is Human Computer Interaction and I am  from US. So when the other prof. asked my MS prof. for borrowing for a day or two to fix his algorithms she denied him saying i was too busy even though i was free (and this happened 3 time). When research sponsors came to my lab and asked for my resume ,she came in between conversations and asked them to forward my resume to her and she would forward it to them. I understood the message and didn't forward my resume to sponsors and i was into conflict avoidance mode with my advisor. I knew she wanted to screw me real bad but she couldn't.

Comment: @james234 did you tell her you were actually free? Did you followed up with her, asking if she had forwarded your CV to the sponsors? I still have a hard time figuring out a reason for her to do active sabotage.

Comment: @Davidmh  Well she never forwarded the resume to them. Infact she actively persuaded the sponsor to recruit a completely new guy who had joined the lab recently . And at multiple times during our meetings she told me to drop my Phd with the tenured prof. and go to other univs and i shouldn't care what the other prof. thinks of it. When i asked her why she never gave me an answer.  I asked my other labmate why she was doing this and he told me that she wanted me to stay in her lab for Phd and the fact that i went to another lab was insulting to her.  But this is all just background info

Comment: If "135K" is in USD, why do you want to break your back over getting a PhD when you're already earning $135K pa? That's an extraordinary amount of money.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that is a typical pay for a data warehouse engineer. My project architect makes over 400K just for FYI. But i am far more interested in research than consulting and working in IT. I just see my present job as a temporary gig to help get me where i want to.

Comment: @james234: Whatever your country is it is mental

Comment: If my understanding is correct and she's still your advisor, then she may be able to intentionally fail you in the exam and brings an end to your PhD.. Do not wait till the exam

Comment: @james234 If you really want a PhD, I'd suggest quitting your job and relocating to a different university.  In my view, if you are not participating in research, you are not getting a PhD.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist In an ideal situation i could do that. Buy i have enquired for funding with most of the professors i know and all of them are content with  continuing with their masters students for PhD. I cannot sustain a Phd with no funding and working on  my job for first couple of years not only eliminates the need for funding , but also i can complete my course requirements in that time. What is the drawback here?

Comment: The drawback of maintaining your job is not doing research, and therefore missing the point of a PhD.  If you can move to a better university there will be more funding opportunities.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I am making up my plan for next 2 years as  i move along .I can do something like volunteer work for a professor to work in their lab over weekends (That gives me atleast 16 hours to work on research ). At this point ,thats all the time i have. So will it be a good idea to ask a professor in HCI dept about that. Also leaving my present university is not an option.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist It seems like the OP is in a PhD programme where the first two years focus heavily on courses (I've only heard of one such case in Europe, but OP is in the US). I would absolutely agree with you if the OP was in one of the situations familiar to me, where you jump into research with no to minimal course requirements at the beginning of (a typically short 3-4 year programme). I am not saying you are wrong, but still wondering if your advice is as much on point for somebody with a mandated course-heavy start of a PhD programme.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's better to be involved in research from the beginning of a PhD program, but I've seen plenty of programs *designed* to discourage starting research until the student has passed the qualifying exams. Both models can lead to good PhDs and good careers afterward. You appear to be in the enviable position, assuming you can sustain it, of being able to save a substantial portion of the salary from your day job so that when it comes time to start some research, you can do so with your own funding. If the project goes well, and you are good at research, you may be able to complete your dissertation more quickly than someone who has to work on a funded grant which has deliverables other than your thesis.

Comment: i am in a pretty weak position within my department now. In Worst case scenario , i may have to go back to my MS advisor  till i pass my candidacy. I need guidance on which subjects to take to reach candidacy. If i ever have to go back to my MS advisor , can i face any potential adverse consequences like willful sabotage of my Phd ?

Comment: Yeah, but if the reason she was sabotaging everything else was because she wanted you to do you PhD with her, then the odds are somewhat lower that she'll sabotage the PhD itself. Though, if she's mad enoug, anything could happen. That being said, I think you need to find someone trustworthy in the department to talk to about the prior sabotage. If it happened as you said, it's something a good department would want to look into and stop.

Comment: i just took your advice and asked an office assistant( a close friend) who processes GRA contracts asking if she has any info. It seems my MS advisor has hired a new Phd student from outside . I have been her MS student for past 2 years and the assistant thought  my MS adviser may have asked me to leave univ. so that she doesn't look bad in the dept. ( the fact she ditched her student and hired new face from outside ).So if i had left the univ. following her advice she could have told people in department that she wanted to offer me Phd but i left for job on my own volition.

Comment: **Find a new advisor, as quickly as possible.**

Answer (score 3):

Where is the department Chair in this situation?  Depending upon the structure of your college within the university, that is generally the individual with whom you can discuss both your questions regarding research and your situation with your MS advisor.  It sounds as if you need someone who can deal with the administrative aspects of the situation - the person who signs your MS advisor's annual review.

If that doesn't work, you can go to the Dean of your college, or perhaps the Dean of Students.  In my years working in Academia, the Dean of Students was always a powerful individual within the university.  You shouldn't have to deal with the petty issues that you're experiencing.  You should be able to focus on your degree and its associated research.